# addToBackStack Not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to close the fragment and wants to resume the main activity by using the addToBackStack in my fragment implimentation but it is not working. Back button is closing the application.

The fragment implimentation method that I am using is,

```
  private void dispaySelectedScreen(int id) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.facebook_login:
            fragment = new FacebookLogin();
            break;
        case R.id.memes:
            fragment = new Memes();
            break;
        case R.id.submit_image:
            fragment = new SubmitImage();
            break;
        case R.id.discussion:
            fragment = new Discussions();
            break;
        case R.id.invite:
            fragment = new Invite();
            break;
        case R.id.connect_fb:
            fragment = new FacebookConnect();
            break;
        case R.id.connect_twitter:
            fragment = new TwitterConnect();
            break;
        case R.id.connect_instagram:
            fragment = new InstaConnect();
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();




    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

I have also declared one onBackPressed method for the drawer,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    }
```

Please suggest..

Comment: try `ft.addToBackStack(null)`

Comment: @aksacha  Not working!!! any other suggestion??

Answer (score 2):

**fragment.addToBackStack(null)** is enough to open the previous activity but if you want to handle some action on back pressed apart from removing the fragment then we override onBackPressed(), so this is my tested approach, kindly have a look:-

Below is my implementation:-

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new MyFragment(), "MY_FRAG")
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAG");
        if (fragment != null) {
            if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                //todo perform any action if you want when fragment is removed
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mrinmoy. I only want to close the fragment and go back to the activity but the addToBackStack(null) is not working. is it because of the "if" condition i have mentioned while implimenting the fragments??

Comment: remove onBackPressed() and try

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using replace on transaction in that way your fragment will pop up from stack but it will reload i.e onCreateView() of that fragment will be called . Just replace

```
 ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
```

to

```
 ft.add(R.id.content_main, fragment);
```

For handling back button use following code .

```
public void onBackPressed() {
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        //that means your stack is empty and you want to close activity
        finish();
    } else {
        // pop the backstack here
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @ADM thanx for the help.. But this not working for me.. I tried replacing the  code as mentioned by you and kept everyting same.. back button is still closing the app.. do i need to change anything else in the fragment implimentation or in the onBackPressed method??

Comment: Not sure whats wrong with the app but it is also not working.. do i need to mention anything in the onKeyDown.. i have created onKeydown for the webview inside the main activity..

Comment: '   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        myWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}'

Comment: There is no need for keyDown just override the onBackpreesed